# Tumblr の customize_api/demo_content からJSONを取得したい

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

https://www.tumblr.com/customize_api/demo_content/user

ブラウザでこのアドレスにアクセスするとテキストノードが得られます。
httpsモジュールとBASIC認証で色々試しましたができませんでした。
nodeのhttpsと必要ならばアカウントデータを使ってJSONデータを取得したいです。
取得できた方いましたらおねがいします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

アカウント持っていないので試せませんが、スクレイピングツールを使えば良いのではないでしょうか。
http://qiita.com/ktty1220/items/64168e8d416d6d8ffb45
ほかにも"node scrape"あたりのワードでググると
x-ray: http://dailyjs.com/2015/02/05/xray/
wscraper: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wscraper
などがある様です。

---

コメント欄に書いたのですが、改行などうまくできなかったのでこちらに追記します。

ログインが必要です。ログインは行いましたか？ログインは下記を参考にしてください。
    http://qiita.com/ktty1220/items/64168e8d416d6d8ffb45#form-elementsubmit-param-callback-
    https://github.com/ktty1220/cheerio-httpcli/blob/master/example/facebook.js
    https://github.com/ktty1220/cheerio-httpcli/blob/master/example/niconico.js

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。cheerio-httpcliをつかってみましたが、JSONデータを取得することができませんでした。ログイン画面に飛ばされているようでした。

Comment: コメント欄に書いたのですが、改行などうまくできなかったので回答に追記しました。